# Inserting a sub list into a list n python

Tags: python, list, insert

I have a list A=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]] and i want to insert [2,2] at index=1 in list A. What should i do? I am not suppose to use any package for this. The final array will be: A=[[1,2],[2,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
The following code I used but it is giving error:

```
A.insert([2,2],1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
A.insert(1, [2, 2])
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.insert(i, x)
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first
> argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
> a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a),
> x) is equivalent to a.append(x).